# What's the difference between `Object.merge(...)` and `Object.append(...)` in MooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Seems like a simple question, but the MooTools documentation for these two methods looks identical.

Here's the code from the documentation:

```
var firstObj = {
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
};
var secondObj = {
    age: '20',
    sex: 'male',
    lastName: 'Dorian'
};
Object.append(firstObj, secondObj);
//firstObj is now: {name: 'John', lastName: 'Dorian', age: '20', sex: 'male'};
```

If I change `append` to `merge`, I get identical results.  So what's the difference?

Comment: just a guess, you'll see differences if the objects have sub objects.

Comment: @MattGreer: I tried with sub objects, and I can't see a difference.

Comment: @MattGreer: Correction: I see a difference is the objects have sub objects, and you make changes to those sub objects.

Answer (score 6):

The only difference that I can see, is that `append` takes two parameters, and `merge` takes two or more parameters.

#### Edit:

Reading the source code of the methods, I see another difference. The `merge` method will clone the properties from the other objects, while the `append` method only copies them.

So, if you have an object or array as a property in some of the objects, those will be reachable from the original object after using `append`:

```
var firstObj = {
    name: 'John',
    lastName: [ 'Doe' ]
};
var secondObj = {
    age: '20',
    sex: 'male',
    lastName: [ 'Dorian' ]
};

//Object.merge(firstObj, secondObj);
Object.append(firstObj, secondObj);

console.log(firstObj.lastName[0]); // Dorian

secondObj.lastName[0] = 'McEnroe';

console.log(firstObj.lastName[0]); // McEnroe
```

If you use `merge` instead, the array item in `furstObj.lastName` will not change when you change `secondObj.lastName`, because they are not the same object.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/PrsXj/

Also, the `merge` method has an overload when the second parameter is a string:

```
merge(obj, "name", obj2)
```

That will only copy the property `obj2.name` to `obj`, i.e, basically the same as `merge(obj, { name: obj2.name })`.

Comment: Very detailed and insightful, nice! Good catch with `.append();` copying the values, and not cloning.